# Using fork() to iterate through directory recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion, directory, fork

So I'm trying to iterate through a directory and its subdirectories, printing out file and subdirectory names. I need to use fork() to create a child process to handle printing the file name or subdirectory name. I'm currently using a recursive function, recursing when a subdirectory is detected; however, the program is outputting duplicate information.

```
void itterate_dir(DIR * dd){//given initial directory dd

struct dirent * curr = NULL;
curr = readdir(dd);//skip initial ./ and .. directories
curr = readdir(dd);
curr = readdir(dd);
while(curr!=NULL){

    int status = 0;
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid==0){
        //in child process
        if(curr->d_type == DT_REG){//is a file

            printf("File:\t%s\n", curr->d_name);

        }else{//is a directory

            printf("Directory:\t%s\n", curr->d_name);
            DIR * dd = opendir(strcat(curr->d_name,"/"));
            itterate_dir(dd);
            closedir(dd);

        }

    }

    wait(&status);

    curr = readdir(dd);

}   

}
```

When I input a directory containing file1, file2, foo_stuff(a subdirectory), file 3 I get the following output

```
File:   f1
File:   f2
Directory:      more_foo
File:   f3
Directory:      more_foo
File:   f3
File:   f2
Directory:      more_foo
File:   f3
Directory:      more_foo
File:   f3
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Is there a better way to go about using fork() to do this without recursion?

Comment: Among other possible issues (such as not descending into the subdirectories), `strcat(curr->d_name,"/")` corrupts the memory because `curr->d_name` does not have space for an exatra `'/'`.

Comment: 1. you don't seem to exit your child , 2. wait(&status) this call is executed by both parent and child I don't think thats what you need ( want ). 3. you don't seem to check return vaues wait for instance